# how to undo bundle update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, bundler

`bundle update` and `bundle install` is ver fantastic.  However, is there a good way to `undo`  `bundle install` and `bundle update` if something went wrong ?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

There is one obvious way:

```
git checkout -- Gemfile.lock
```

and then run

```
bundle install
```

It assumes you use `git` - but who does not now days, I have everything in git.

Comment: git checkout by default tries to checkout git branch, if you specify `--` it knows it has to checkout files ... it's only in case you would have a branch named the same as one of your files - but it's a good habit.

Answer (score 6):

I went into Github, copied my old `Gemfile.lock` that I wanted and pasted it into my `Gemfile.lock` in my code and then ran `bundle install`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow the accepted answer but I was still getting errors. This is what worked for me:

```
git checkout -- Gemfile.lock
```

And then:

```
bundle pristine
```

As described in the [Bundler docs](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-pristine.1.html), `bundle pristine` restores installed gems to their pristine condition.